# Adding Application Insights on Blazor Client (Web Assembly)

Tags: azure-application-insights, blazor-webassembly

I am wanting to add application insights sdk into a blazor web assembly project. I came across multiple articles such as [Application Insights for web pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#snippet-based-setup) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60008023/blazor-client-side-wasm-application-insights) that has the exact thing I am looking for. However, after adding the snippet of code from the microsoft link and using connectionString over instrumentationKey to the `index.html` page and injecting `IJSRuntime` in order to call JavaScript methods from .NET code then calling Application Inisghts methods... when running the application at the top of the home page I will see @inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime.

[image]

Am I not properly setting up the injecting? Also, do I need to add these lines of code into each razor component (page folder) or just having it in the `index.html` will cover everything from the start to end no matter what I click and what page is rendered?

`Index.html`

```
@inject IJSRuntime _jsRuntime

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        !function (T, l, y) { var S = T.location, k = "script", D = "connectionString", C = "ingestionendpoint", I = "disableExceptionTracking", E = "ai.device.", b = "toLowerCase", w = "crossOrigin", N = "POST", e = "appInsightsSDK", t = y.name || "appInsights"; (y.name || T[e]) && (T[e] = t); var n = T[t] || function (d) { var g = !1, f = !1, m = { initialize: !0, queue: [], sv: "5", version: 2, config: d }; function v(e, t) { var n = {}, a = "Browser"; return n[E + "id"] = a[b](), n[E + "type"] = a, n["ai.operation.name"] = S && S.pathname || "_unknown_", n["ai.internal.sdkVersion"] = "javascript:snippet_" + (m.sv || m.version), { time: function () { var e = new Date; function t(e) { var t = "" + e; return 1 === t.length && (t = "0" + t), t } return e.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + t(1 + e.getUTCMonth()) + "-" + t(e.getUTCDate()) + "T" + t(e.getUTCHours()) + ":" + t(e.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + t(e.getUTCSeconds()) + "." + ((e.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1e3).toFixed(3) + "").slice(2, 5) + "Z" }(), iKey: e, name: "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights." + e.replace(/-/g, "") + "." + t, sampleRate: 100, tags: n, data: { baseData: { ver: 2 } } } } var h = d.url || y.src; if (h) { function a(e) { var t, n, a, i, r, o, s, c, u, p, l; g = !0, m.queue = [], f || (f = !0, t = h, s = function () { var e = {}, t = d.connectionString; if (t) for (var n = t.split(";"), a = 0; a < n.length; a++) { var i = n[a].split("="); 2 === i.length && (e[i[0][b]()] = i[1]) } if (!e[C]) { var r = e.endpointsuffix, o = r ? e.location : null; e[C] = "https://" + (o ? o + "." : "") + "dc." + (r || "services.visualstudio.com") } return e }(), c = s[D] || d[D] || "", u = s[C], p = u ? u + "/v2/track" : d.endpointUrl, (l = []).push((n = "SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details)", a = t, i = p, (o = (r = v(c, "Exception")).data).baseType = "ExceptionData", o.baseData.exceptions = [{ typeName: "SDKLoadFailed", message: n.replace(/\./g, "-"), hasFullStack: !1, stack: n + "\nSnippet failed to load [" + a + "] -- Telemetry is disabled\nHelp Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128109\nHost: " + (S && S.pathname || "_unknown_") + "\nEndpoint: " + i, parsedStack: [] }], r)), l.push(function (e, t, n, a) { var i = v(c, "Message"), r = i.data; r.baseType = "MessageData"; var o = r.baseData; return o.message = 'AI (Internal): 99 message:"' + ("SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details) (" + n + ")").replace(/\"/g, "") + '"', o.properties = { endpoint: a }, i }(0, 0, t, p)), function (e, t) { if (JSON) { var n = T.fetch; if (n && !y.useXhr) n(t, { method: N, body: JSON.stringify(e), mode: "cors" }); else if (XMLHttpRequest) { var a = new XMLHttpRequest; a.open(N, t), a.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"), a.send(JSON.stringify(e)) } } }(l, p)) } function i(e, t) { f || setTimeout(function () { !t && m.core || a() }, 500) } var e = function () { var n = l.createElement(k); n.src = h; var e = y[w]; return !e && "" !== e || "undefined" == n[w] || (n[w] = e), n.onload = i, n.onerror = a, n.onreadystatechange = function (e, t) { "loaded" !== n.readyState && "complete" !== n.readyState || i(0, t) }, n }(); y.ld < 0 ? l.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e) : setTimeout(function () { l.getElementsByTagName(k)[0].parentNode.appendChild(e) }, y.ld || 0) } try { m.cookie = l.cookie } catch (p) { } function t(e) { for (; e.length;)!function (t) { m[t] = function () { var e = arguments; g || m.queue.push(function () { m[t].apply(m, e) }) } }(e.pop()) } var n = "track", r = "TrackPage", o = "TrackEvent"; t([n + "Event", n + "PageView", n + "Exception", n + "Trace", n + "DependencyData", n + "Metric", n + "PageViewPerformance", "start" + r, "stop" + r, "start" + o, "stop" + o, "addTelemetryInitializer", "setAuthenticatedUserContext", "clearAuthenticatedUserContext", "flush"]), m.SeverityLevel = { Verbose: 0, Information: 1, Warning: 2, Error: 3, Critical: 4 }; var s = (d.extensionConfig || {}).ApplicationInsightsAnalytics || {}; if (!0 !== d[I] && !0 !== s[I]) { var c = "onerror"; t(["_" + c]); var u = T[c]; T[c] = function (e, t, n, a, i) { var r = u && u(e, t, n, a, i); return !0 !== r && m["_" + c]({ message: e, url: t, lineNumber: n, columnNumber: a, error: i }), r }, d.autoExceptionInstrumented = !0 } return m }(y.cfg); function a() { y.onInit && y.onInit(n) } (T[t] = n).queue && 0 === n.queue.length ? (n.queue.push(a), n.trackPageView({})) : a() }(window, document, {
            src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js", // The SDK URL Source
            // name: "appInsights", // Global SDK Instance name defaults to "appInsights" when not supplied
            // ld: 0, // Defines the load delay (in ms) before attempting to load the sdk. -1 = block page load and add to head. (default) = 0ms load after timeout,
            // useXhr: 1, // Use XHR instead of fetch to report failures (if available),
            crossOrigin: "anonymous", // When supplied this will add the provided value as the cross origin attribute on the script tag
            // onInit: null, // Once the application insights instance has loaded and initialized this callback function will be called with 1 argument -- the sdk instance (DO NOT ADD anything to the sdk.queue -- As they won't get called)
            cfg: { // Application Insights Configuration
                connectionString: "CONNECTIONSTRING_KEY_GOES_HERE"
                /* ...Other Configuration Options... */
            }
        });
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>BlazorWeb</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BlazorWeb.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>

    await _jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("appInsights.trackPageView");

</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Injecting the Application Insights for Blazor web applications. Steps to be followed

- Add [BlazorApplicationInsights
  Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorApplicationInsights)

  dotnet add package `BlazorApplicationInsights`
- Add call to Program.cs

  `builder.Services.AddBlazorApplicationInsights();`
- Add using statement to _Imports.razor

  `@using BlazorApplicationInsights;`
- Add component to App.razor

  `<ApplicationInsightsComponent />`
- Add Application Insights JS to head in index.html

  [Source](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#snippet-setup-ignore-if-using-npm-setup)

  Set 'ld: -1' so that the page will be blocked until the JS is loaded and enter your `instrumentationKey`

  Add the  [Source](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS#snippet-setup-ignore-if-using-npm-setup) like below screenshot

[image]

- Add JS Interop to the bottom of body in index.html

[image]

I can see the Track Event button which I was used.

[image]

Also, I can see the custom Event in Application Insights.

[image]

Refer [here](https://github.com/IvanJosipovic/BlazorApplicationInsights)

Comment: Wow you are a lifesaver, thank you!!